# What is the equivalent of jQuery's $(".cell:first") in D3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, d3.js

I've tried

```
d3.select(".cell:first")
d3.selectAll(".cell").filter(":first")
d3.selectAll(".cell").select(":first")
```

but neither work

Comment: but then I would lose the D3 object and `d3.select(d3.selectAll(".cell")[0])` seems a little redundant

Comment: For a deeper explanation: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/  Great read!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`d3.select(".cell")` already selects the first matched element:

> Selects the first element that matches the specified selector string, returning a single-element selection. If no elements in the current document match the specified selector, returns the empty selection. If multiple elements match the selector, only the first matching element (in document traversal order) will be selected.

Source: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_select

#### *"How would I get the last item?*"

D3 appears to return the results of `d3.selectAll()` in a collection, positioned in an array. For instance, requesting all paragraphs on the [d3 homepage](http://d3js.org/) results in:

```js
[ Array[32] ] // An array with a single array child. Child has 32 paragraphs.
```

So if we wanted to get the last paragraph from that collection, we could do the following:

```js
var paragraphs = d3.selectAll("p");
var lastParag  = paragraphs[0].pop();
```

Or more concisely:

```js
var obj = d3.select( d3.selectAll("p")[0].pop() );
```

#### *"What about :last-child?"*

The `:last-child` selector isn't the same as getting the last element on a page. This selector will give you the elements that are the last child of their parent container. Consider the following markup:

```html
<div id="foo">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>World</p>
  <div>English</div>
</div>
<div id="bar">
  <p>Oie</p>
  <p>Mundo</p>
  <div>Portuguese</div>
</div>
```

In this example, running `d3.select("p:last-child")` won't return any of your paragraphs. Even `d3.selectAll("p:last-child")` won't. Neither of those containers have a last child that is a paragraph (they are `<div>` elements: `<div>English</div>` and `<div>Portuguese</div>`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jonathan. Maybe I was confused in thinking that there was a selector called `:first`, as there is one called `:first-child`, so in D3 I can do `d3.selectAll(".cell").filter(":first-child")`, so I guess `:first` is jQuery specific. For your answer I would still have to do `d3.select(lastParag)` to be able to use it as a D3 object

Comment: @nachocab You don't have any reason to do `:first-child`, as the documentation states. The `d3.select()` method already returns the first element. Not to mention, that wouldn't return the first paragraph, but rather the first paragraph that also happens to be the field child of its parent.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the first DOM element from the D3's selection, use `.node()` method:

```
var sel = d3.selectAll('p'); // all <P>, wrapped with D3.selection
var el = sel.node(); // the first <P> element
```