# Floating repeated divs, how to keep XY together

Tags: javascript, html, floating

I am currently creating many figures using the JavaScript library D3 (but I don't think D3 has any relevance for my problem). The figure is placed in `div X` and the text explaining the figure is in `div Y`. I basically want to create a pattern like this:

```
XYXYXY

XYXYXY
```

but instead (depending on how wide my window since I do not want to fix the width), what I get this:

```
XYXYX

YXYXY
```

I tried putting `XY` in a parent `div Z<XY>`, so that every pair of `XY` stays together, but that does not work. I also don't think clearing is necessarily the answer here, but I have tried all combinations without success.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show some of your current work on this - you can use http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
white-space: nowrap
```

You may also have to change the floats to for your XY divs:

```
display: inline-block
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly, you don't need to use `float`. Display the divs as inline blocks: `display: inline-block`.

That will flow the divs as "character blocks" doing the wrap, you'll need to have a parent for the XY to keep the text together with the image.

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/D9BAv/

HTML:

```
 <div class="figure">
   <div class="picture"></div>
   <div class="text">Example 1</div>
 </div><!-- reapeated ... -->
```

CSS:

```
 .figure {
   display: inline-block;
 }
 .picture {
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    margin:auto;
    background-color: blue;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly, maybe this will work. You could also use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` if you don't need to support IE8 and below.

http://jsfiddle.net/GQ8Uw/

HTML

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="x">X</div><div class="y">Y</div>    
</div><div class="cont">
    <div class="x">X</div><div class="y">Y</div>    
</div><div class="cont">
    <div class="x">X</div><div class="y">Y</div>    
</div><div class="cont">
    <div class="x">X</div><div class="y">Y</div>    
</div><div class="cont">
    <div class="x">X</div><div class="y">Y</div>    
</div>
<div class="cont">
    <div class="x">X</div><div class="y">Y</div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cont {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

.x, .y {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.x {
    background: #ccc;
}

.y {
    background: #ecc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem. So I was wrong, it did have something to do with D3. Each time, I was essentially adding a child div to the same parent, and therefore the inline-block simply had no effect.

I ended up adding a "last-child" feature in my code like "d3.select(".figure:last-child").append(...", for both the picture and the text, and it works perfectly.

I saw the problem by adding a border around the parent div, and I noticed that all children were in the same div. I then found the solution from: [What is the equivalent of jQuery's $(".cell:first") in D3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640430/what-is-the-equivalent-of-jquerys-cellfirst-in-d3)